# evolutions against test mysql database with scala play specs2

Tags: database, scala, playframework, specs2

I'm using specs2 for integration tests with Scala Play (2.3) and I'm using a mysql database for testing, rather than than an H2 database. My test cases use WithApplication and FakeApplication with a configuration override of db.default.url to specify a test (mysql) database.

The issue is that no evolutions are run. Test cases all bomb out because no tables have been created.

If I run the application normally, not under test, and Apply Evolutions, then dump this database and load into the test database, all tests pass fine (I clean out all tables between test runs to ensure a clean database for each test).

Why aren't evolutions run automatically? What can I do to get them to run? Note: I do not want to use H2 and InMemoryDatabase. I want to use mysql for tests, just as I do in production. I've found various solutions on the 'net for manually locating and running evolutions, but none of these solutions maintain the "play_evolutions" table and I've not managed to get them to work correctly in Play 2.3.

Comment: hi, would you provide a code sample of how to run fake app with mysql database ?

Answer (score 1):

Play evolutions by default will only run manually. This is obviously a problem when testing because you can't be prompted to run them. In your `FakeApplication` you may need to set the following under `additionalConfiguration`:

```
"evolutionplugin" -> "enabled",
"applyEvolutions.default" -> true, 
"applyDownEvolutions" -> true
```

So your `FakeApplication` might look like this:

```
val app = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map(
    "db.default.driver" -> "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "db.default.url" -> "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
    "db.default.user" -> "...",
    "db.default.password" -> "...",
    "evolutionplugin" -> "enabled",
    "applyEvolutions" -> "false"
))
```

Alternatively, you can also drop the custom `FakeApplication` and fallback to what's in `application.conf`.

Note that this is only going to run the evolutions when it says that `play_evolutions` doesn't exist or is inconsistent. So if you want to clean it up after each test, you'll need to drop the tables yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following setting to your config file

```
applyEvolutions.default=true
```

where "default" is the name of your database.